# Positive positive negative negative Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What is the simplest series that alternates in order $+,+,-,-,+,+,-,- \dots$

Specifically I want to make a Riemann sum for something, but it has this reoccurent pattern I haven't previously encountered. Normally I have seen $(-1)^n$, but this is new to me.

Comment: Do you mean sequence rather than series?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I suppose it doesn't matter in this case, I edited in my motivation for clarification.

Comment: Oh, I see, so what you actually want is a simple formula for $f(n) = \left\lbrace\begin{matrix}1 & n=1,2,5,6,\ldots\\-1 & n = 3,4,7,8,\ldots\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: @M.Vinay Precisely, that would definitely have been a better way to describe the problem on reflection.

Comment: @DisplayName (still think that's a weird name...) I've updated my answer with such a function.

Comment: My answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/823883/21820 will in this special case be equivalent to *David H*'s answer below, and in general some combination of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(n) = (-1)^{\dfrac{(n-1)(n + 2)}{2}} = \left\lbrace\begin{matrix}1, & n = 1,2,5,6,\ldots\\-1, & n = 3,4,7,8,\ldots\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: $(3-1)(3+2) = 2*5=10$, $(-1)^{10} = 1$?

Comment: @DisplayName Oops, I missed a $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Corrected.

Comment: Very nice, this is probably my favourite form!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by simplest. The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$, where $a_n = \operatorname{Re}(i^n) + \operatorname{Im}(i^n)$, follows this pattern.

Comment: Sorry, what are $Re$ and $Im$?

Comment: The real part and imaginary part respectively.

Comment: @DisplayName You can also write this as $\cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)$. Note that $n$ starts from $0$, not $1$ (for the sequence to be $1, 1, -1, -1, \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the sequence $1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,...$ can be described by the formula

$$f(n)=\sin{\frac{\pi n}{2}}+\cos{\frac{\pi n}{2}}.$$